# How to create alpha_encoder.exe (webm-tools) under msys2?

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw-w64, webm, msys2

I'm trying to compile *alpha_encoder*) (little utility of [The WebM Project](http://www.webmproject.org/code/), under *webm-tools*).
I have a previous installation of *msys2* (downloaded and configured by [build_locally_with_various_option_prompts.bat](https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/blob/master/native_build/build_locally_with_various_option_prompts.bat)) under `c:\FFcompiler`. It took its time, but I managed to compile *ffmpeg*, so I decided to use it (I think it will do). That's what I've done till now.

First, I cloned *webm-tools* under `/cygdrive/c/FFcompiler/ffmpeg_local_builds/sandbox/win32/libvpx-1.4.0/third_party/`. There's a `Makefile` so I tried to run `make`:

```
$ cd /cygdrive/c/FFcompiler/ffmpeg_local_builds/sandbox/win32/libvpx-1.4.0/third_party/
$ git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/webm-tools.git
$ cd webm-tools/alpha_encoder/
$ make
```

But *g++* complains `mkvparser.hpp` doesn't exist. The command is

```
g++ -c -W -Wall -O3 -g -I../../libwebm alpha_encoder.cc -o alpha_encoder.o
```

After searching the web, it seems that *webm-tools* depends on *libwebm*, and expect finding it as a sibling folder of *webm-tools*. So...

```
$ cd ../..
$ git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/libwebm.git
$ cd libwebm
```

Now, what? `README.libwebm` tells that 'to cross compile libwebm for Windows using mingw-w64' first I must run `cmake` like this `cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path/to/libwebm/build/mingw-w64_toolchain.cmake path/to/libwebm`. In my case:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=build/mingw-w64_toolchain.cmake .
```

And `cmake` cannot find *i686-w64-mingw32-g++*. After googling more, it seems the easiest way to fix this is to add `bin` of `mingw-w64-i686` to `PATH`.

```
$ export PATH=/cygdrive/c/FFcompiler/ffmpeg_local_builds/sandbox/cross_compilers/mingw-w64-i686/bin:$PATH
```

After this, now `cmake` finishes successfully and creates a `Makefile`, but  `make` stops with an error:

```
/cygdrive/c/FFcompiler/ffmpeg_local_builds/sandbox/win32/libvpx-1.4.0/third_part
y/libwebm/common/file_util.cc:44:39: error: 'tmpnam_s' was not declared in this
scope
   errno_t err = tmpnam_s(tmp_file_name);
                                       ^
```

I've searched about the error but I'm stuck. What am I missing?

Comment: [It looks like](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/tmpnam) you need either a newer c compiler, or you missed to enable c11 in the compiler flags.

Comment: I installed _msys2_ using the mentioned `.bat`  less than 2 weeks ago - I suppose it's updated. About the flags, does that mean than I must tweak the `Makefile`? Does not `cmake` take care of the suitable flags? Anyway, how could I test the system to find out what of the two things is?

Comment: You can tweak the CMakeLists.txt, You'll need to add `-std=c99` to the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS ` variable.

Comment: I found no `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` in CMakeLists.txt but there is a `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` section so I tried `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c99 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")` (nothing to lose). Now `make` outputs several times `cc1plus: warning: command line option '-std=c99' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++` and stops with the same scope error on `tmpnam_s`.

Comment: For the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ` use `-std=c++11`.

Comment: After cleaning `CMakeFiles` folder and running again _cmake_ and _make_, now there are 2 errors: The first is `file_util.cc: In function 'std::__cxx11::string libwebm::GetTempFileName()':`; the other is the same of `tmpnam_s`.